# Outputting a class with Rivets.js?

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I thought this would be easier unless I'm missing something but I can't figure out how to output a piece of my data as a class.

`<div class="partner-type" rv-class="partner.partner-type"></div>`

doesn't work. It should say the value in that property "technology" or "service". Is there anyway to do string interpolation or something? Data attrs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using something like

`rv-class-ineededthisclass="partner.partner_type | isNotEqual 'premier'"`

Btw, this library is great for rivetsjs:
https://github.com/matthieuriolo/rivetsjs-stdlib

Answer (score 2):

You can find in the [official Github documentation page](https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/wiki/Custom-Binders), a simple custom Binder which behaves exactly as you require: It assigns dynamically the className stored in your variable, to the bound element.

> ### **AddClass (rv-addclass)**
>
> Adds a new class to the element (using the attribute value)
> in addition to any existing ones. On subsequent changes, the
> previously added class is replaced with the new one.

Binder declaration:

```
rivets.binders.addclass = function(el, value) {
  if (el.addedClass) {
    $(el).removeClass(el.addedClass);
    delete el.addedClass;
  }

  if (value) {
    $(el).addClass(value);
    el.addedClass = value;
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
<i rv-addclass="partner.partner_type"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I have created a binder called "rv-set-class" to solve the problem.

```
rivets.binders['set-class'] = function(el, value){
     el.className += ' '+ value;   
}
```

You can now use it like this:

```
<div rv-set-class="partner.partner-type"></div>
```